# How to use active record as DTO to my business objects

Tags: python, django, architecture

I struggle with this problem for a long time. I searched and searched the whole internet for solution but nothing was acceptable for me.

In short, to react Daniel's comment:

I would like to use the Django's Active Record ORM's objects but only as a DTO with the ability to save the data back to the database, including complex relationships. 
This way my business objects would be independent of it's data sources and they would only contain behavior.

Long version:

We started a project which looked very simple in terms of business logic required, so I picked Django as a framework to make things easier. The problem got complex and maybe the implementation will be used in a much larger project so I want to decouple my business objects objects from activerecord and **I want to use django only as a DB backend and something what uses my objects**. The UI is already decoupled from the start, it only calls a REST API provided by the django backend.

My problems with an example:
I have a Request model which connected to many other models. This request contains some requirement specification related to networks. These networks are associated to a Cloud models. The networks under a cloud will be connected to the reservation which is generated from the request (currently they are connected to the request's nw descriptors to determine the configurations during queries).

```
class Request(Model):
  ...  # bunch_of_stuff_here

class NetworkDescriptor(Model):
  request = ForeignKey(Request)
  configA = ...
  configB = ...

class Cloud(Model):
   ...

class Network(Model):
   cloud = ForeignKey(Cloud)
   used_by = ForeignKey(NetworkDescriptor)
```

Solutions I considered:

1) Embed the models to the BOs and delegate to them. 
This leads to the following problem: When i try to access the networks of a cloud and simply delegate, for example with

```
def get_networks:
  return orm_dto.networks
```

i get back AR objects, which is bad. I don't want to leak the AR details here. I would have to write a mapper to from ORMNetworks to BOnetworks, which tracks the changes of networks `( network.used_by=request )`. This by definition an Object Mapper... which i already have (namely ORM) and i dont want this. :)

2) Embed the models but allow only high level interaction. This sounds much more Object Oriented, but still don't know how to do it:

```
class Cloud:
  def serve_request(bo_request):
    ???
```

The result should be a bunch of networks where the used_by field is set to the ORMRequest object which is behind the BORequest parameter. How should i get this information? If i don't want to leak the ORM details, again... i have to write something which tracks the BO objects and can map them to AR objects, for example:

```
class Cloud:
  def serve_request(bo_request):
    for net in self._find_matching_networks(bo_requsets)
      net.used_by = repo.get_ar_from_bo(bo_request)
```

which is again... not the best solution because i have to write the mapper, but in this case it seems much easier because i don't have to take care of the related fields.

3) Use Template Method pattern and make the AR objects to be only a data source.

```
class Request(Model, Resource):
  def get_cpu():
    return self._cpu

class Resource(object)
  def __le__(self, other:Resource):
    return self.get_cpu() <= other.get_cpu()
```

This is again a solution which i don't like because in this case the AR still the BO. I can't unit test it effectively without reaching the DB, but at least on code level the business part is separated from the Data access part.

4) Complete swap to SqlAlchemy. The problem is that the administartion of AR objects through Django is much easier than it would be with alchemy, but maybe this is the ultimate solution.

Comment: You're using a lot of names here you haven't explained. What are AR, BO, ORMNetworks, ORMRequest, BORequest? What exactly is your problem? Why would SQLAlchemy make it bbetter?

Comment: AR stands for ActiveRecord, BO stands for BusinessObject.

Comment: In the first solution if I use Business Objects, there should be a BO variant of every AR object, and this solution would only solve the unit testability problem.
ORM stands for Object-Relational Mapper, and ActiveRecord is a common pattern to map Relational Data to Objects (DTOs, to be specific)

Comment: SqlAlchemy uses Data Mapper pattern which is much more flexible and more complicated, and meanwhile AR object contains all the logic to save itself, in data mapper case this responsibility goes to other object.
As far as i know SqlAlchemy objects can be instantiated without hiting the database, but in Django's AR case it is not possible in every scenario.